# Float right moves the span element up?

Tags: html, css

Hi i have beeen trying to make `span` and `h1` element on the same line. However `float:right` will result span to move top. I have tried with different approach, i dont want to use margin property. Any sugesstions on this?

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.pull-right: {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1 class="pull-left">Carl</h1>
  <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Its just the default margin of h1 tag that is doing this, you need to remove that.

If you wanna vertically center the span based on h1 then just use line-height:*font-size of h1*

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/redhawx/hyb0ybag/)

```css
.block h1
    {
      margin:0px;
    }
    .block span
    {
      line-height:2em;
    }
    .pull-left{
      float:left;
      width:70%;
    }
    .pull-right:{
      float:right;
      width:20%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1 class="pull-left">Carl</h1>
  <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have applied `pull-left` class on `<h1>` and all html headings have some margin applied by browsers by default. If you will apply `pull-left` to a `<div>` then you will not see any extra space but if you will use `<h1>` or some other heading then you need to remove default `margin` from heading.

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
h1.pull-left {
  margin: 0;
}
span.pull-right {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <h1 class="pull-left">Carl</h1>
    <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>
```

If you wants heading and span as middle aligned then better to use `inline-block` as follows:

```css
.block h1,
.block span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block h1 {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}

.block span {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Carl</h1>
  <span>$4.81</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u explain the answer :)

Comment: Still span is moving to top

Answer (score 1):

Use display inline css value:

```
<h1 class="pull-left" style="display:inline">Carl</h1>
<span class="pull-right" style="display:inline">$4.81</span>
```

Comment: Test it and put the display:inline; in CSS classes

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height` to make different sized texts in same level.

```css
.pull-left {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <h1 class="pull-left">Carl</h1>
    <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>
```

What we've done here is, we made both `h1` and `span` same height even though they have different `font-size`.

Check the MDN link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Answer (score 1):

Use table-cell & vertical align that's equally vertically align your text

```css
.block{
display:table;
width:100%;
}
.pull-left{
  width:70%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.pull-right{
   width:20%;
   display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <h1 class="pull-left">Carl</h1>
    <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the start of your css file :

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```